# Can PhantomJS be used with py2exe?

Tags: python, wxpython, phantomjs, py2exe

I'm running my wxPython exe that uses PhantomJS fine on my computer. However, after I send it over to another computer, it gives the error below. If this was a standard package or module in the Python library, I would be able to figure this out but PhantomJS is quite complex it seems. Do I need to include something in my py2exe settings to make phantomjs.exe to work with my app? Or do I just include the phantomjs.exe in my dist folder?

```
File "selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.pyc", line 50, in __init__
File "selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.pyc", line 67, in start
WebDriverException: Message: 'Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.' ; Screenshot: available via screen
```

Thanks so much! There's not much info about py2exe and phantomjs available.

Comment: Is there a phantomjs.exe on the second computer preferably in the PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I couldn't find a solution through py2exe, so I manually changed the path of phantomjs to "phantomjs.exe" and then manually copied it into my distribution folder. I then zipped it and it shipped to the end user fine.